# DJango WOPI server error when submit iframe

Tags: django, office365, ms-wopi

I'm implementing a custom wopi server to communicate a custom documenty library with office 365. The implementation is based on a django server which implements all wopi endpoints. That server communicates a cloud document library server with wopi.

The problem is that when I submit the iframe to open a document with the office 365 I get the following error in javascript:

```
Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Invalid BaseDocQuerySignature in appSettings
    at Error.create (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/h60A82C06E357C29F_App_Scripts/MicrosoftAjaxDS.js:1:20454)
    at Error.invalidOperation (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/h60A82C06E357C29F_App_Scripts/MicrosoftAjaxDS.js:1:22209)
    at jE.abb (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/hF07758D5927F3735_App_Scripts/WordEditorDS.js:5411:21)
    at jE.abb (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/hA7BA4A856D543B08_App_Scripts/WordEditorDS.core.js:2433:281)
    at jE.abb (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/hA7BA4A856D543B08_App_Scripts/WordEditorDS.core.js:694:121)
    at jE.m0d (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/hA7BA4A856D543B08_App_Scripts/WordEditorDS.core.js:2432:362)
    at jE.m0d (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/hA7BA4A856D543B08_App_Scripts/WordEditorDS.core.js:687:269)
    at jE.initialize (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/hF07758D5927F3735_App_Scripts/WordEditorDS.js:5423:235)
    at jE.initialize (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/hA7BA4A856D543B08_App_Scripts/WordEditorDS.core.js:2428:58)
    at new nj (https://res-v-sdf.cdn.office.net/officeonline/we/s/hA7BA4A856D543B08_App_Scripts/WordEditorDS.core.js:639:463)
```

I searched for that error on the web, but all the solutions implies modify office 365 code.

The index.html that I'm using is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>vvwopi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../static/js/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://c1-word-view-15.cdn.office.net/wv/resources/1033/FavIcon_Word.ico" />

        <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            -ms-content-zooming: none;
        }

        #office_frame {
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: none;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="wopiTest">
            <h1>VisualVault WOPI Test</h1>
            <p>
                Use this page to demo the WOPI host implementation
            </p>
            <p>
                Discovery file: https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery
            </p>

            <button class="wopi_editDoc_button" id="vwWopiTest" onclick="formSubmit('office_wopiTest_form')">Wopi Test Document</button>

            <form id="office_form" name="office_form" target="office_frame" action="" method="post">
                <input name="access_token" value="" type="hidden" />
                <input name="access_token_ttl" value="" type="hidden" />
                <input name="user_id" value="" type="hidden" />
                <input name="owner_id" value="" type="hidden" />
            </form>

    </div>

    <span id="frameholder"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        let windowUrl = (new URL(window.location));
        let hostName = windowUrl.hostname;
        let testMode = params.get('test');

        let testDiv = document.getElementById('wopiTest');
        if(testDiv){
            testDiv.style.display = "none";
        }

        if(params){
            updateForm(params);
        }

        function updateForm(params){
            let dlId = params.get('dlid');
            let token = params.get('token');
            let userId = params.get('userid');

            let wopiForm = document.forms['office_form']; //document.getElementById('office_form');
            let wopiClientActionUrl = "{{ wopi_action_url | safe }}";
            let wopiClientParams = `?IsLicensedUser=1&WOPISrc=https://${hostName}/wopi/files/${dlId}`

            wopiForm.elements["access_token"].value = token;
            wopiForm.elements["access_token_ttl"].value = '1702137445000'; //todo: make dynamic;
            wopiForm.elements["user_id"].value = userId;
            wopiForm.elements["owner_id"].value = userId;

            wopiForm.action = `${wopiClientActionUrl}${wopiClientParams}`;
            formSubmit('office_form');
        }

        function formSubmit(name) {
            var frameholder = document.getElementById('frameholder');
            var office_frame = document.createElement('iframe');
            office_frame.name = 'office_frame';
            office_frame.id = 'office_frame';

            // The title should be set for accessibility
            office_frame.title = 'Office Online Frame';

            // This attribute allows true fullscreen mode in slideshow view
            // when using PowerPoint Online's 'view' action.
            office_frame.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', 'true');

            // The sandbox attribute is needed to allow automatic redirection to the O365 sign-in page in the business user flow
            office_frame.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups allow-top-navigation allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox');

            //office_frame.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups allow-top-navigation allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-downloads allow-modals');
            //office_frame.setAttribute('allow', 'autoplay camera microphone display-capture');

            frameholder.appendChild(office_frame);

            document.getElementById(name).submit();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the part that is failing is the submit of the last line of the script part:

```
document.getElementById(name).submit();
```

Thanks for your help!!!